# HighCharts: How to format particular label column?

Tags: css, highcharts, label

I need to show the label values inside the Highcharts bar chart. It can be implemented using `dataLabels.Formatter` function.

But when the bar is in consist-able size the labels are shown inside the bar and it is looking good. In some cases, the bar is very small in size comparing to the label.

Please see the code pen here, https://codepen.io/JGSpark/pen/YzzBydv?editors=1010

The last bar is very small and 40 is showing outside. As the `color: 'white'` is commonly used for all the labels it is showing in white though it is in outside.

How can I change the color of the label if it is showing out?

In this example, I need to change the color of label 40 to black. Any suggestions?

Comment: I am seeing Label color as black whether its inside bar or not, please check your codepen.

Comment: @CodeReady Please check the code pen again. I have done some updates

Comment: So you need color of label to be changed if it is outside the bar?

Comment: Yes, Exactly @CodeReady

Comment: Add ```formatter: function() {
                    var max = this.series.yAxis.max,
                        color =  this.y / max < 0.05 ? 'black' : 'white'; // 5% width
                    return '<p style="color: ' + color + '">' + this.y + ' M</p>';   
                },``` as your formatter and it should work. Let me know if this is what you needed.

Comment: Yes, Thank you its working

Answer (score 1):

You need to add custom formatter which will check the size of yAxis value and will change the color of label accordingly:

```
formatter: function() { 
    var max = this.series.yAxis.max,
    color = this.y / max < 0.05 ? 'black' : 'white'; // 5% width
    return '<p style="color: ' + color + '">' + this.y + ' M</p>';
},
```

Comment: FYI!! This is not working in all the cases. Still looking for the answer :(

Comment: Can you mention a case.

Comment: https://codepen.io/JGSpark/pen/YzzBydv?editors=1010 - updated code pen with the sample case

Comment: You just need to play with ```this.y / max < 0.05``` condition, if you change ```0.05``` to ```0.01```, your case will work. However, the color will only change if the number is completely outside the bar.

Answer (score 1):

If your chart is not a dynamically created you can set the dataLabels.color for the particular point.

```
{
  y: 40,
  dataLabels: {
    color: 'black'
  }
}
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/wvrbs4mq/)

[API](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.data.dataLabels)

EDIT

Another solution which I can suggest is to add a functionality inside the chart.events.load which will filter if dataLabels is aligned to left or right and set wanted color - it will work if more labels will be outside the column bar.

```
    events: {
  load() {
    let chart = this,
      series = chart.series;

    series[0].points.forEach(p => {
      if (p.dataLabel.alignOptions.align === 'left') {
        p.dataLabel.css({
          color: 'black'
        })
      }
    })
  }
}
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/pbf0n1ms/)
[API](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.load)

Comment: No, In my case I need to calculate it dynamically. If any better idea, always welcome

Comment: Its not generic, It is only changing the color of series 40. What happen if I change the series value 1001 to 10. It is showing it in still white

Comment: @JeyaSuriyaMuthumari I have changed the load functionality to render - this will work after each redraw, please check it now: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/wLdaujqc/

Comment: update your data series with this, data: [1216, 10, 4436, 738, 240, 150, 132], Check if it still works !!.. I am not sure. how to make it work .:(

Comment: @JeyaSuriyaMuthumari I updated the above demo with your data and each dataLabel which moves outside the column bar change color to the black. Is not what you had in mind? https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/hpm0uqg3/

Comment: Uhh... 150 and 132 are not fully inside the bar neither outside the bar. It is partially in and partially out. But I need it to be fully outside.